# Java: how to make a method return an array of classes

Tags: java

I want a method to return some thing like:

```
{classA.class,classB.class,classC.class}
```

I've tried:

```
public Class<?>[] methodeName()
{
   return {classA.class,classB.class,classC.class};
}
```

but this won't complie, as Java thinks that I want to create a class ... I don't want to use any lists ....

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let's take a look at the bigger picture: why do you want to return an array of classes and why don't you want to use a List?

Comment: there is even more code to write to create them.

Comment: Not really:  `Arrays.asList(classA.class, classB.class, classC.class);` The big question is, why do you need a method to return a collection of classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to properly create the array:

```
return new Class<?>[]{classA.class, classB.class, classC.class};
```

What you're trying to do only works in with array *declarations:*

```
Class<?>[] classes = {classA.class, classB.class, classC.class};  // <--
return classes;
```

Array creation expressions are detailed in [JLS §15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10).

Comment: thanks, I'v tried to do it in a too complicated way ... what I really needed was simply a static arry in my class and no methode returning one as I just wanted a static array of classes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell that the type is `Class`

```
return new Class[] {classA.class, classB.class, classC.class};
```

Where

```
 return {classA.class,classB.class,classC.class};// Compiler is asking  what 
                 type of array it is ?? I can't store without knowing its type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    public Class<?>[] methodeName()
    {
       Class<?>[] classes= {classA.class,classB.class,classC.class};
       return classes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll work

```
Class[] fun(){
    Class[] i = {classA.class,classB.class,classC.class};
    return i;
}
```